# HQL sum of difference between two columns

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

A simple hibernate related question.
How can I do something equivalent to this SQL code :

```
    select sum(COLUMN_A - COLUMN_B) from some_table;
```

I tried using both columns inside the sum property like this:

```
    Projections.sum("COLUMN_A - COLUMN_B")
```

With no success once hibernate will search for a property called COLUMN_A - COLUMN_B which obviously does not exist.

Any alternatives ?

Comment: You can get sum of `column_a` and `column_b` separatly and then substract it in java

Comment: Ok that is a good idea, I can load both sum´s to some custom object and then add them.

Comment: Its looks like ii impossible to do what you want with creteria api.

Comment: @Reimeus Yes, but we do not see full pictute. Maybe there are lot of effort invested in creating complex query in criterea api and changing all those code will lead to more work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a `Projections.sqlProjection`?

Something like

```
Projections.sqlProjection("SUM(COLUMN_A - COLUMN_B) as sumOfDifferences", new String[]{"sumOfDifferences"}, new Type[] {IntegerType.INSTANCE})
```